# sequelizejs: How to change return value structure?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
{
    "name": "AA",
    "Category": {
        "id_category": 354,
        "id_parent": 342,
        "position": 0
    }
},
{
    "name": "AAA",
    "Category": {
        "id_category": 355,
        "id_parent": 342,
        "position": 1
    }
},
```

Class **CategoryLang** belongsTo One **Category**, Class **Category** has many **CategoryLang**. How can I change return data like below:

```
{
    "name": "AA",
        "id_category": 354,
        "id_parent": 342,
        "position": 0

},
{
    "name": "AAA",
    "id_category": 355,
    "id_parent": 342,
    "position": 1
    }
},
```

Repost:
Here is my query, I used **include** function. Maybe there is another keyword could fix it. But I didn't find it.

```
  db.Category.findAll(
    {
        attributes: ['id_category','id_parent','position'],
        where: { id_parent:parentId ,active: 1},
        order:'position',
        include : [{
            model:db.CategoryLang,
            where: { id_shop: 1, id_lang: 1 },
            attributes: ['name','description','link_rewrite']
        }]
    }
).then((categories) => {
    return resultReturn.returnFormattedResult(
        res,
        true,
        "Success",
        categories
    );


}).catch((err)=> {
    res.status(400);
    return  resultReturn.returnFormattedResult(
        res,
        false,
        "Can not get Categories"
    );

});
```

Comment: What does your query look like ?

Comment: @TGrif . I posed.